# Usage of 'loading' property in ApolloGrapQL client for Angular

Tags: angular, observable, graphql

First, here's some Angular code [from the ApolloGraphQL official doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/queries.html).
Please, focus on the `.subscribe()` section.

[image]

The description says:

[image]

When I run this code, the callback is called only once, and the result is always:

```
{
    loading: false,
    data: ...
}
```

Now, my questions are:
Why did they wrote `this.loading = loading` instead of `this.loading = false` directly?
How many times the closure in `.subscribe()` ***can*** be called for a single call of `.ngOnInit()`?
Do the `loading` field can be truthy sometimes?

✌

Comment: "How many times the closure in .subscribe()".  from docs -**Apollo.watchQuery <..> can emit multiple results** and because you subscribed - yes,it can be fired many times. "Do the loading field can be truthy sometimes?" - thinking it can not, makes no sense :)

Comment: Hum.. I thought I could use this `loading` property to show a spinner, without initializing `this.loading` to `true` just before the request.

Comment: I dont know this API, so I am just guessing. I read that `valueChanges()` returns `Observable<QueryRef>`, not  the `Observable<HttpEvent>` (as usual in Angular's `get()`), so maybe there are no such things as "success" and "error" callbacks, so when you subscribe, function gets executed no matter the query was successfull or not. If thats true, it explains why they dont just `this.loading = false`. And why they don't set `loading = true` in initial state, not sure, as from that exact implementation, seems that might be logical to do (I mean when they subscribe in OnInit)

Comment: @popStar, Then shouldn't it be `this.status` instead of `this.loading`? The fact that it is `this.loading` makes me wonder if this `loading` field gets updated whenever the request status is changed.

Comment: `loading` seems fine as there are only 2 values - true or false

Answer (score 0):

The closure is just call once, and its returning an object with two properties,

```
{ loading, value }
```

**Apollo** cannot control what happens inside of your `subscribe function` that is why you cannot set, `this.loading = false` (in this way you are hardcoding the answer).

The way in which callbacks works, is to pass values as arguments to a function that is going to be called in the future.

As the description says the loading is going to be true if is is set the `watchQuery` parameter to true but also if the request is not 'in-flight' (perhaps to some error).

**Updated**

[From docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/queries.html), "The observable will only emit once when the query is complete" (`valueChanges`). `watchQuery` exposes an `Observable` aka `valueChanges`.

`Apollo.watchQuery` also does the same (returns an Observable that emits a result, just once), except it can emit multiple results **but** (and this is pretty important to keep in mind) **The GraphQL query itself is still only sent once**, but the watchQuery observable can also update if, for example, another query causes the object to be updated within Apollo Client’s global cache.

Comment: Yep. But why did they call this field `"loading"`? It may be just a naming issue, but it makes me wonder if the `this.loading = loading` gets called everytime the request status changes. In fact, as I understand this piece of code, when the `.subscribe()` closure is called, the `loading` param is always falsy. Why? because the request is finished!

Comment: No, it is not get called everytime the request status changes but when another query causes the object to be updated within Apollo Client’s global cache. I updated the answer, let me know if I was clear enough.